# How can I get size of prototype cell in descendant of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a class that is descendant of UICollectionView. I'm using storyboards.

How can I get size of prototype cell in it ?

I tried calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` in `awakeFromNib` but I get `Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7fffdc))` in console.

I need cell size because I want to change layout in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can get it like this:**

```
CGFloat height = [[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableIdentifier] bounds].size.height;
```

But if you get bad access in `awakeFromNib` probably you should paste some code from that custom cell.

Comment: you answer is to UITableView, while question was about UICollectionView

Comment: same goes for UICollectionView

Comment: Well... no, because for collection method is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath and can't be used here.

Comment: It's: dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: - and why you cannot use it ?

Comment: because of crash at that point, try it yourown, with storyboard case.